# Getting wrong results for country names using geograpy3

Tags: python-3.x, geograpy

I tried running the example code as given in the readme file for [geograpy3](https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3/). However, I am getting answers like this. What can be done about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question raises a similar issue as https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3/issues/3

There is now a get_geoPlace_context function that will limit the search to the GPE label of NLTK thus ignoring PERSON and ORGANIZATION entries as the orginal function get_place_context would do:

see also [test_extractor.py](https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3/blob/master/tests/test_extractor.py)

```
 def testGetGeoPlace(self):
    '''
    test geo place handling
    '''
    url='http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-26919928'
    places=geograpy.get_geoPlace_context(url=url)
    if self.debug:
        print(places)
    self.assertEqual(['Moscow', 'Donetsk', 'Brussels', 'Kharkiv', 'Russia'],places.cities)
```